# Logout or end session using itsdangerous signing

Tags: flask, token, access-token

If I create a token for my API like this:

```
def generate_auth_token(self, **kwargs):
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in = 172800)
    return s.dumps({ 'id': kwargs['user_id'] })
```

How can I end a user's session?

Answer (score 2):

You can't if that's the only information in the token.  You can solve this by adding more information to the token payload, and possibly storing extra information about valid tokens server side.

For example, you could store a hash of the email and password, so if either changes, the hash will not compare anymore

```
from hashlib import md5
from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp

# generate the hash and store it in the token along with the id
hash = md5('{}{}'.format(user.email, user.password).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()

###

# load the user from the id in the token and generate its hash
hash = md5('{}{}'.format(user.email, user.password).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()

# then compare the hash in the token to the hash for the user
if not safe_str_cmp(hash, token['hash']):
    # don't log in user
```

This is done in a hash rather than just including the email and password directly because the token is *signed* but not *encrypted*.

If you want to be able to invalidate all tokens without changing the email or password, you can store some random key per user and add that to the hash.  Generating a new random key will invalidate all previous tokens.

You could also take this even further and just store the full tokens server side, removing them on logout so they can't be used again.